May the ViewModel class be derived from Model class? MVVM
Developing a WPF Application with MVVM Pattern: ViewModel and Model Interface/Abstract Class Dilemma
Currently, I am developing a WPF application that adheres to the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern. The application already includes some view code that presents a user interface by implementing DataTemplate for various Model classes. To ensure a proper separation of concerns and to prevent the View from directly knowing about the Model, I decided to create wrapper classes for these Model classes within the ViewModel.
However, I am now faced with a design decision regarding the implementation of the ViewModel class. Specifically, I need to determine whether the ViewModel should be a completely new class or if it should implement an existing interface or abstract class from the Model.
Main Question:
If I choose to implement an interface or abstract class from the Model in my ViewModel, does this imply that the View will have some level of awareness about the Model? Is this approach aligned with the principles of the MVVM pattern, or does it violate the separation of concerns?
Additional Question:
To encapsulate some logic within the ViewModel, I am considering a constructor in the ViewModel that accepts an instance of a Model class and is marked with internal access. Will this design choice impact the testability of my code? How can I ensure that my ViewModel remains testable if such internal constructors are used?
Example:
In my application, I have a Model with a hierarchy of classes:

Square, Sphere, Cube, and Ellipse, all derived from a base class FigureBase.

There are also various other classes that work with FigureBase.
In total, there are over 20 classes derived from FigureBase, each with unique properties that need to be modified through the UI using DataTemplate and then saved/serialized for future use.
Should the View code directly create a DataTemplate for each Model class such as Square, Ellipse, etc., or should each of these classes have a corresponding ViewModel wrapper like SquareWrapper which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and handles serialization logic?

"If I choose to implement an interface or abstract class from the Model in my ViewModel, does this imply that the View will have some level of awareness about the Model?" - In short, as long as the view model does not implement model functionality (which itself would be a violation) or exposes the model to the view, there can't be any "awareness" (dependency) between view and model. It all boils down to not making model references in the view model public and to taking care that the view model implements the correct responsibilities.

If this is true, then view model and model can implement the same interfaces or extend the same classes. For example, if the view model implements ISaveToFile then this would likely violate the MVVM pattern as MVVM classifies data persistence as a responsibility of the model.

An abstract class on the other hand usually provides a default behavior. While it is more likely that this behavior ends up in the wrong component if shared between MVVM components, there are still cases where this could make sense. Again, it depends on the behavior you are going to inherit. If the only goal is to allow a view model class to use model functionality by letting it extend model classes, then this is generally a bad design (no matter the design pattern you are following). As mentioned before, in such cases classes must use other classes and not derive from them.

"To encapsulate some logic within the ViewModel, I am considering a constructor in the ViewModel that accepts an instance of a Model class and is marked with internal access. Will this design choice impact the testability of my code? " - This is very common practice, especially when you use dependency injection. To test the view model class you have to mock the constructor dependencies (e.g. the model classes). If you pass dummy objects to the constructor you are able to test the view model properly.

However, if you don't use dependency injection you could run into trouble, because in this case the view model classes are usually instantiated by the view classes. And you can't allow the view classes to instantiate model classes as this introduces a tight coupling. In this scenario it would be better to use composition over aggregation i.e. instantiate model classes inside the constructor instead of passing them to the constrictor (instantiation inside vs outside the class).


If I choose to implement an interface or abstract class from the Model in my ViewModel, does this imply that the View will have some level of awareness about the Model?

The view will always have some level of awareness of the model, since it is intended to present data from the model to the user. So there will by necessity be some level of coupling between the model and view.

Is this approach aligned with the principles of the MVVM pattern, or does it violate the separation of concerns?

The pattern specifies a separate model and view model, so it seem difficult to argue that it does not goes against the pattern.
But as with any pattern it is a good idea to think about what problem it is intended to solve and when and where it is applicable. The view model tend to be full of things like handling and presenting errors, dealing with translations, verifying input etc. So it usually make sense to separate these concerns from the concerns of the model. There is also a general recommendation of composition over inheritance that highlights some of the problems of overuse of inheritance.
But it is perfectly possible that these concerns are not relevant for your particular use case. Perhaps there are no input verification, translations or error handling to worry about? Perhaps this is a short lived application where maintainability is less important?
In the end I would recommend using a separate model and viewmodel, but do not bend over backward just to fulfill some design pattern. Think about what you are doing and why, talk with your colleges, and do whatever you think is best for your particular situation.

@BionicCode Yes, MVVM does not allow a direct dependency, but that does not mean that the model and view is totally independent. I.e. the data that is visible to the user will need to have some relation to the data that is stored.

I see. but this is wrong understanding. If data had been relevant then all MVVM components would violate the pattern as all components at some point share the same data. I mean how can view and model have different (business) data? However, they don't share data objects. An application usually has business data that we display to the user. The point of MVVM is to create a rule for how data is passed across predefined application boundaries (the MVVM boundaries).

For example, we must have a view and a model component and we are not allowed to pass data directly from model to the view. We have the view model as intermediate component to decouple view from the model. MVVM does not focus on data. No design pattern does. Design patterns focus on functionality and dependencies.  OO dependencies exist between objects and not data. Functionality targets data. And because MVVM classifies functionality, we know that data persistence is a responsibility of the model component and e.g. presentation of the same data to the user a responsibility of the view.

MVVM cares that those (data related) responsibilities are separated. MVVM introduces an application structure (the view, view model and model components) and describes how these components interact with each other. Data is not relevant. MVVM is about application structure and the responsibilities and interaction of the components that make the structure. Who (which MVVM component) is allowed to do what with the data and who passes data to whom.

And that's why it is generally allowed that view, view model and model implement the same interfaces and extend the same classes - as long as the implementations and inherited functionalities do not. violate the MVVM rules.

@BionicCode I think we are in agreement of the general concept, but perhaps not not the specific terminology I have used, and perhaps some philosophical details. With "some level of coupling" I meant any there will exist some kind of indirect dependency between these components. Would you formulate this in a different way?

@BionicCode I'm not sure what your point about MVVM not being data focused is. The wiki defines the viewModel as "a value converter, meaning it is responsible for exposing (converting) the data objects from the model in such a way they can be easily managed and presented" , (and back again). I might misunderstand your point, but that sounds fairly data focused to me.

"there will exist some kind of indirect dependency between these components" - Technically, there exists a direct coupling (unidirectional). And we can consider data binding an indirect coupling (the event source anonymously invokes the callback of event listener). But there can't be any event handlers of the view that are invoked by the model. "The view will always have some level of awareness of the model" - This is just not correct. That was my point.

The complete application is data focused. Butt MVVM describes dependencies between its components. There exists no such thing as dependencies between data.. MVVM describes how each component is allowed to handle data (view model: presenting data to the view, view: displaying data to the user, mode: applying business rules, data persistence etc.).

And data objects is not data. View model converts between data objects. But it will pass along the same data it received from the model to the view. As I understood it, this was your point why there exists an indirect dependency between view and model, because view handles the same data (not data objects) as the model: "model and view is totally independent. I.e. the data that is visible to the user will need to have some relation to the data that is stored. ". MVVM successfully manages to make view and model totally independent of each other. tha's the whole point of MVVM.

Let alone details and interpretations. We can say that per definition (explicit, no interpretation possible) there is no relation/awareness/dependency between view and model. And that the dependency are strictly unidirectional from view to view model to model. And that MVVM does describe what MVVM components are allowed to do with data or in other words the responsibilities of each MVVM component.

In my opinion there is not much room for interpretation. All we have to do is to define our classes in a way that we don't violate the MVVM application level dependency graph after we have associated a class with an appropriate component. The only indirect dependency MVVM allows is the one introduced by events, which is the only way data can travel against the default data flow direction (view->view model->model).

When I said "not data focused" I meant that MVVM does not care about the fact that data of the model also exists in the view. All it cares about is how this data gets there and how it gets back (across the MVVM boundaries i.e. between the MVVM components). I said this to make a point why this can't be relevant in terms of introducing any kind of "indirect" awareness as you described it.
